# Attach authenticated user to create

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to attach the currently logged in user to this request, so that I can save it in the database. Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

```
public function store(CreateLeadStatusRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $leadStatus = $this->leadStatusRepository->create($input);

        Flash::success('Lead Status saved successfully.');

        return redirect(route('lead-statuses.index'));
    }
```

So, I have come up with the following using `array_merge`, but there must be a better way, surely?

```
public function store(CreateLeadStatusRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $userDetails = array('created_by' => Auth::user()->id, 'modified_by' => Auth::user()->id);
        $merged_array = array_merge($input, $userDetails);
        $leadStatus = $this->leadStatusRepository->create($merged_array);

        Flash::success('Lead Status saved successfully.');

        return redirect(route('lead-statuses.index'));
    }
```

Comment: You can use \Auth::user() to get the currently authenticated user.

Answer (score 1):

So you can use `Auth` Facade to get information of currently logged user.

For Laravel 5 - 5.1

```
\Auth::user() \\It will give you nice json of current authenticated user
```

For Laravel 5.2 to latest

```
\Auth::guard('guard_name')->user() \\Result is same
```

In laravel 5.2, there is new feature called Multi-Authentication which can help you to use multiple tables for multiple authentication out of the box that is why the `guard('guard_name')` function is use to get authenticated user.

This is the best approach to handle these type of scenario instead of attaching or joining.

```
public function store(CreateLeadStatusRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $userDetails = \Auth::user(); //Or \Auth::guard('guard_name')->user()
    $leadStatus = $this->leadStatusRepository->create($input);

    Flash::success('Lead Status saved successfully.');

    return redirect(route('lead-statuses.index'));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: note that \Auth::user() will still work in 5.2. It will grab the user off the default guard.

Comment: Yeah, it will work for default `guard` specified in  `config/auth.php`. so if you use different authentication then you have to specify guard. :)

Comment: @imrealashu thanks for the answer. My question was more centred around how I send the current user ID in to the request.

Comment: @showFocus Could you be more specific? 'send the current userID to the request' doesn't make any sense. Do you mean return the id with the response? You can get the ID with `$id = \Auth::user()->id`. Then you can do whatever you need to with `$id`

Comment: @jfadich sorry, still working on my terminology :) So the request comes in, but the created_by and modified_by are not part of that request. I would like to insert the authenticated user_id in to the created_by and modified_by fields as part of the store method. You'll notice I have updated my question using an array_merge, it works, which is great. But even as a novice I *think* this can be done better.

Comment: @showFocus The merge works, but requires 'created_by' to be in the fillable array which I personally don't like because it opens you up to the possibility that users can change the relationships directly (if they do send 'created_by' in the request). If you have relationships defined you can also do `$leadStatus->createdBy()->save(\Auth::user());`

Comment: @jfadich thanks, I knew it wasn't the best solution. I've just tried yours but the ID doesn't seem to get passed a along causing a "Integrity constraint violation"

Comment: @showFocus It depends on how the relation is set up. You might try `$leadStatus->createdBy()->associate(\Auth::user());`

Comment: @jfadich `public function createdBy()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }`

Comment: Ah, the column is not 'user_id' therefore I have to specify it in my association?